# SQL Count Number of Occurrences for a Multi-Row Distinct, By Multi-Row Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I have a query that sums all values from the "Total" column and aligns them to their unique combination of storename, year, make, and model (via a Group By):

```
    select storename, year, make, model, sum(total) as [Sum]
    from #TempTable
    group by storename, year, make, model
```

An example of the results:

```
    StoreA 2009 TOYO    AVALON  1039.95
    StoreB 2005 CHET    TAHOE   1039.99
    StoreC 2010 MAZD    CX-9    1040.07
    StoreD 2007 DODG    CHARGER 1040.09
    StoreE 2003 ACUT    MDX     1040.17
```

What I want to do is add another column to this query that counts how many rows exist in each Group. For example, I know there are 5 instances of a 2009 TOYO AVALON at StoreA, but I want the script to figure out how many there are for each unique combination of storename, year, make, model. And I want it displayed as an extra column [CarCount] to the right of [Sum].

There must be a way, but I have not been able to find a solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add count(*) to the query it will count the number of instances in that group

```
 select storename, year, make, model, sum(total) as [Sum], count(*) carcount 
    from #TempTable
    group by storename, year, make, model
```

Comment: Valli, thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood, you need the count on the existing grouping. Just use `COUNT` to get it.

```
select storename, year, make, model, sum(total) as [Sum], COUNT(1) as CarCount
    from #TempTable
    group by storename, year, make, model
```

Comment: AB_87, thank you for your answer! It is very similar to the one proposed by Valli above. I ran both queries and they produce the same results, so I am wondering what the difference between count(*) and count(1) would be?

Comment: @JordanMcDonald There was no answer when I submitted mine. We both submitted almost at the same time. It happens. There are many questions around `COUNT(1)` and `COUNT(*)`. Below is the link to one of the most popular questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1